# Prepaid SIM card for US and Canada

Tags: usa, canada, internet

I'm travelling to Canada and the US for three weeks. Is there a prepaid sim card that can work in both countries? I would mainly need it for data. No calls.

Comment: Maybe either US Mobile prepaid or T-Mobile prepaid might suit your needs. I haven't checked carefully into their roaming capabilities, though.

Comment: Alternatively, you could buy a "world-traveler" or "global" or "international" SIM. But that might be more expensive. Compare prices carefully.

Answer (score 2):

The [$60 AT&T Gophone plan](https://www.att.com/shop/wireless/plans/planconfigurator.html?tab=gophone&plan=basic) provides a month of service that includes roaming in Canada (and Mexico). You might need to start your trip in the US to make this practical, however.

Comment: The AT&T Gophone plan no longer includes Canada roaming. :(